# Making an employee and assignment list in scheme and ran into syntax error

Tags: scheme

I'm having an issue with my Scheme program. I had to define a function `(jobs_ok? Assignment Employees)` where `jobs_ok?` takes in `Assignment` and `Employees` as two parameters and `Assignment` and `Employees` are two lists that contain sublists. `Assignments` is supposed to take in 4 names, where the names are assigned to a specific job. For each of the 4 sublists it's assigned and `Employees` is supposed to take in the names entered into `Assignment` where it has a person's name followed by three integers (either 1 or 0) and returns true if the integer is 1 for the job that person is assigned to or false otherwise. I wrote down my code but for some reason it says there's a syntax error near unexpected token `'jobs_ok?'` and then it shows the line below: `'(define (jobs_ok? Assignment Employees)'`.

So I was wondering what is wrong with my code? Here's my code below:

```
(define (jobs_ok? Assignment Employees)
  (define (Assignment 9:00-11:00 11:00-1:00 1:00-3:00 3:00-5:00)
    (define (9:00-11:00 phone1 phone2 computerRepair networkRepair)
      (cond ((string? phone1 phone2 computerRepair networkRepair) #F)
            (#T (phone1 phone2 computerRepair networkRepair))))
    (define (11:00-1:00 phone1 phone2 computerRepair networkRepair)
      (cond ((string? phone1 phone2 computerRepair networkRepair) #F)
            (#T (phone1 phone2 computerRepair networkRepair))))
    (define (1:00-3:00 phone1 phone2 computerRepair networkRepair)
      (cond ((string? phone1 phone2 computerRepair networkRepair) #F)
            (#T (phone1 phone2 computerRepair networkRepair))))
    (define (3:00-5:00 phone1 phone2 computerRepair networkRepair)
      (cond ((string? phone1 phone2 computerRepair networkRepair) #F)
            (#T (phone1 phone2 computerRepair networkRepair)))))
  (define (Employees employeeName)
    (define (employeeName phone1 phone2 computerRepair networkRepair)
      (define (phone1 phone computer network)
        (cond ((= phone 0) #F) (#T phone1)))
      (define (phone2 phone computer network)
        (cond ((= phone 0) #F) (#T phone2)))
      (define (computer phone computer network)
        (cond ((= computer 0) #F) (#T computer)))
      (define (network phone computer network)
        (cond ((= network 0) #F) (#T network)))))
  (cond ((equal? (Assignment) #F) #F) ((equal? (Employees) #F) #F) (#T jobs_ok?)))
```

Here is how I ran it in mobaxterm: `./jobs_ok.scm < testscheme`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains many errors, including:

- define inside define
- function called without required arguments
- function string? called with four arguments

You should delete this code and write it again, but test it after each step and see, what every part does, before you put them together.

This problem is actually available online- it has much longer instructions and different meaning of three integers after name. This solution should work:

```
(define (check-shift Shift Employees)
  (and (= 1 (first (cdr (assoc (first Shift) Employees))))
       (= 1 (first (cdr (assoc (second Shift) Employees))))
       (= 1 (second (cdr (assoc (third Shift) Employees))))
       (= 1 (third (cdr (assoc (fourth Shift) Employees))))))
           
(define (jobs_ok? Assignment Employees)
  (and (check-shift (first Assignment) Employees)
       (check-shift (second Assignment) Employees)
       (check-shift (third Assignment) Employees)
       (check-shift (fourth Assignment) Employees)))
```